# Facebook Open Graph Sharing Debugger not reading my code well

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

When I check my url on open graph debugger and click on scrape again

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvsrbija.online%2Findex.php

I get an strange error

> our page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
>   Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

But everything with my code is fine when you look into the source.
I tried scraping blank index.php file, and when i do, here is what Facebook sees

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head></html>
```

But there is no such code, If i go to blank index.php page of my site and check the source it is blank...

BUT, when i use index.html instead of index.php Facebook sees no code as it should with an empty index.php

Problem is my script is php and not html so i can not use html extension to fix problem. I even tried rewriting .php extension to html because I thought maybe Facebook handles it differently but with no luck.
Also I try pausing Cloudflare for couple of days and the same thing...

What can it be?

**EDIT:** Here you can see how Facebook sees my source code https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvsrbija.online%2Findex.php

Comment: Someone commented (now is comment removed and i don't know who it was so i'm responding) and said my html is missing, i replaced

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 10 ]>
<html lang="sr-RS" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="old-ie no-js">
<![endif]--><!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!--><html lang="sr-RS" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->`

with just

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>` and that didn't fixed the problem

Comment: The meta-tags need to be in <head> and you can't have anything before then.

You have: `<body>
<p>&#65279;
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <!--<![endif]-->
</p>`

Comment: I do not, that url i provided is facebook messed up source my real source you can find in your browser

`view-source:https://www.tvsrbija.online/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing encoding to UTF8 without boom instead of just utf8. This has been a headache for many developers because utf8 adds info before file indicating file is utf8

Answer (score 3):

In the provided source link, your output does not have a page head. It must have a valid head and body node to be valid html markup. You can see this in the first three lines of the response body provided by facebook:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<p>&#65279;
```

Facebook is likely converting your `<head>` tag into a `<body>` tag because your source does not contain a `<body>`. Your index.php page should scrape like this to be correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body></body></html>
```

In the future, validate your html markup using the w3c validator to be sure it is correct:

https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Please see a REAL source from your pc

`view-source:https://www.tvsrbija.online/`

I DO have a body open and close tag, and i do not have anything before head tag except for doctype html and <html> ofc

Comment: It looks like you have some output before your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration. See: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvsrbija.online%2F

Comment: Probably echoing a line break or space somewhere, or you have a close `?>` tag somewhere in the previous scripts that has a space or line break after it. In files that only execute code, you do not need a closing tag, which will prevent that problem. Output buffering can also be used to prevent that problem.

Comment: only thing i have before doctype is
`$og = "https://www.tvsrbija.online/images/og.png";
$title = Početna;
ob_start();
require('header.php');`

Header.php is:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><html lang="sr-RS"><![endif]-->
<head>` etc

Comment: In your first file that loads, put `ob_start();` somewhere right toward the beginning. Right before your doctype, put `ob_end_clean();`. That will discard any whitespace or other junk that may have crept in somehow.

Comment: i already have that, i didn't put whole code, see now

`$og = "https://www.tvsrbija.online/images/og.png";
$title = Početna;
ob_start();
require('header.php');
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%", $title,$buffer); 
$buffer=str_replace("%og%", $og,$buffer); 
echo $buffer;`

Comment: Just for a record, other network like g+ or twitter display my og image and other meta tags just fine. i have just problem with facebook

Comment: Looks like from the w3c validator you have multiple issues that you should clean up. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvsrbija.online%2F

Comment: This might be breaking it: `The document is not mappable to XML 1.0 due to two consecutive hyphens in a comment.

At line 900, column 8

 </div>↩ <!----End-wrap---->↩ `

Comment: I'd just go through the list from w3c and start crushing everything until it resolves. The XML one is likely the issue, or the doctype stuff.

Comment: if w3c says it's valid though, it should work pretty much everywhere

Comment: Change your comment blocks to `<!-- Comment -->` instead of `<!----Comment---->` to make XML resolve

Comment: ^ This is probably what is making facebook choke

Comment: I removed all unnecessary comments, no xml markup error more. Fb still reads code wrong.
I cant find blank space before doctype though :(

Comment: I just removed all of my code, and i left this only
`<?require('header.php');?>`
And it stills shows blank space before doctype, which is IMPOSSIBLE.
Maybe i should use include instead of require?

Comment: Do any files that load before the output have close tags `?>` at the end? Take them out if they do.

Comment: Put the following in line 1: `register_shutdown_function(function(){var_dump(get_included_files();)});`

Comment: That will dump a list of everything loaded, in order from start to end. One of those has your output. You may have in a php.ini file some random thing being included before anything happens, or some other such silliness.

Comment: Then look at the list at the end of the page, and make sure you have checked if anything loads before header.php, and that it does not have whitespace at the end if so.

Comment: There are no custom php.ini files not in public_html or in /home/user/ dir
I am using WHM cpanel with standard php configuration.

Comment: Did you get anything in the list before header.php and your index.php?

Comment: I'm pretty sure code you gave me is not doing anything

Comment: View page source, it will be at the end

Comment: NO there is not, i put it on first line in index php even before require or anything else like you said. 

<?
register_shutdown_function(function(){var_dump(get_included_‌​files();)});
$og = "https://www.tvsrbija.online/images/og.png";
$title = Početna;
ob_start();
require('header.php');
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%", $title,$buffer); 
$buffer=str_replace("%og%", $og,$buffer); 
echo $buffer;
?>

Comment: My bad, I typed it wrong. Like this: `register_shutdown_function(function(){var_dump(get_included_files());});`

Comment: I do not see anything except i think it aligned source code?

view-source:https://www.tvsrbija.online/

Comment: Ok, so I manually checked your source as text input. I used `<html lang="sr-RS">` instead of all the if IE stuff, and all the doctype errors went away.

Comment: So I'd wrap that chunk in php conditional logic that just outputs a regular <html> tag without the ifs in the case of facebook.

Comment: OK i did it, but it still shows erorrs what exactly did you do

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr-RS">
<head>`

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr-RS">
<head>`, Just copied source and pasted as text.

Comment: put `ob_start();` again at the beginning. After all your includes, put `trim(ob_get_clean());` which will print everything, but trim whitespace and junk characters off of both ends of the output.

Comment: Yeah but look, if you go to view source of my page ctrl a and then ctrl v in direct input of w3, it will stills how you blank eror as when checking site.
I do not know why i do not see blank when viewing source in chrome on line 1, but w3 somehow sees

Comment: It's probably a null character or something stupid like that. `trim(ob_get_clean());` at the very end should fix that, if that's the case.

Comment: Assuming you did `ob_start();` at the beginning, and it hasn't been flushed or discarded.

Comment: also make sure you're using `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: Yea looks like the doctype is fixed now

Comment: Nope, head's not there at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131299/discussion-between-mopsyd-and-darktwen).

Comment: No,

I had to put it back after require if i put it before ?> page crash

`<?
ob_start();
$og = "https://www.tvsrbija.online/images/og.png";
$title = Početna;
require('header.php');
$buffer=ob_get_contents();
trim(ob_get_clean());
$buffer=str_replace("%TITLE%", $title,$buffer); 
$buffer=str_replace("%og%", $og,$buffer); 
echo $buffer;
?>`