# Open Graph share debugger scrapes empty html

Tags: html, next.js, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to set up Open Graph meta tags for a website. When I access the site normally using a browser and inspect the source, the tags are there. However, they don't show up when I use the OG debugger.

The site that I'm developing is here [spurafrika-org.vercel.app](https://spurafrika-org.vercel.app) (Next.js site). It's replacing the original site here: [spurafrika.org](https://spurafrika.org) (WordPress site).

When I use the **See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL** feature, I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body><p>ÿþ</p></body>
</html>
```

See for yourself [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fspurafrika-org.vercel.app%2F). Vastly different from my actual source for my websites.

I originally thought it might have been a Vercel/Next.js issue, but when I discovered it also happening on the WordPress site, I was very confused: see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fspurafrika.org%2F). I've checked other sites developed with Next.js and WordPress - the meta tags work fine on the debugger.

Another point of confusion is that the debugger tool seems to be able to pick up that on my Next.js site I've listed https://spurafrika.org as its canonical URL, which it can only tell through my og:url tag. Yet when I view what the debugger supposedly sees, it shows the above empty HTML snippet.

I thought perhaps it might have been an [encoding or parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291912/facebook-open-graph-sharing-debugger-not-reading-my-code-well), but I've validated my HTML source using several tools and there are no problems.

I'm stumped. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code against a code sandbox - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fkzi2c.csb.app%2F

Initially keeping the `og:url` as *https://spurafrika.org/* caused warnings and `og:description` not getting picked up, once i pointed it to the actual url it all got fixed

Change the `og:url` to the right url may fix it, give it a shot and let us know.